# vtortola WebSocketListener cannot write on websocket

Tags: vb.net, websocket

I am using the WebSocketListener from [vtortola](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener) and I'm having some issues with the socket throwing an error and then closing itself. I think its happening if I request too much data over the socket all at one time. I am streaming multiple jpeg images over 1 socket. So I can be getting 50+ requests for images per second. Sometimes it happens faster than others and sometimes not at all.

errors:
aex.message = "Cannot write on websocket"
aex.innerException = "Write timeout."

I have this implemented in a vb.net API project that returns back all the images over 1 single socket. For the most past its working fine except for this random error that then closes the socket.

The error gets caught in the try/catch and then closes itself. If I comment out the ws.close() and the ws.Dispose(), the socket still closes itself.

```
Private Shared Async Function HandleConnectionAsync(ws As vtortola.WebSockets.WebSocket, cancellation As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Task)
    ' A request is made
    Console.WriteLine("Connection " + ws.RemoteEndpoint.Port.ToString() + " opened. " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))

    Try
        While ws.IsConnected AndAlso Not cancellation.IsCancellationRequested
            msg = Await ws.ReadStringAsync(cancellation).ConfigureAwait(False)
            If msg IsNot Nothing Then
                Using messageWriterStream As WebSocketMessageWriteStream = ws.CreateMessageWriter(WebSocketMessageType.Binary)
                    image = Await GetImage()
                    If image IsNot Nothing Then
                        Await messageWriterStream.WriteAsync(image, 0, Int(image.Length), cancellation).ConfigureAwait(False)
                    End If
                End Using
            End If
        End While
    Catch aex As Exception
        ws.Close()
    Finally
        ws.Dispose()
        Console.WriteLine("Connection " + ws.RemoteEndpoint.Port.ToString() + " closed. " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: What is the error text generated when the "random error" closes the socket? This probably can be seen from the message text of your exception (aex.Message).

Comment: Updated post, somehow thought i put the error messages in the original post..

Comment: Hi! I assume this was already fixed, right?
https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/issues/115

Comment: Yes it was, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was answered and fixed in the project itself,  [here](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/issues/115)